# How to hide menu with javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile, navigationbar

I found this code on the web and i need help figuring out how to make is so when i click on one of the li elements the menu hides. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/E4Zgj/203/

```js
var originalNavClasses;

function toggleNav() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('navigation_list');
    var classes = elem.className;
    if (originalNavClasses === undefined) {
        originalNavClasses = classes;
    }
    elem.className = /expanded/.test(classes)
        ? originalNavClasses
        : originalNavClasses + ' expanded';
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation">
    <a class="menu_button" href="#footer_nav" onclick="toggleNav(); return false;">
        &#9776;  MENU
    </a>
    <ul id="navigation_list" role="navigation">
        <li><a href=#>HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href=#>SERVICES</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href=#>WORK</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href=#>CONTACT</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What have you tried? post in more detail what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You mention `gallery` as a link but it doesn't exist anywhere

Comment: I do not see a gallery link. Also when you say hide do you mean slide it up like how it is prior to opening it? Or do you actually want the entire nav bar to disappear?

Comment: Slide it like how it is prior opening. The gallery link doesnt matter, just when i click on one of the li elements i want it to slide up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var nav = document.getElementById('navigation_list');

function toggleNav(e) {
    nav.classList.toggle('expanded');
    e.preventDefault();
}

document
    .getElementById('navigation')
    .getElementsByClassName('menu_button')[0]
    .onclick = toggleNav;

nav.onclick = toggleNav;
```

Note I have removed the inline event listener in your html, and attached it using JS instead.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/E4Zgj/205/)

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle is using MooTools, not sure if that is the library you're using or not but this is what you need to do in jQuery. I don't know MooTools:

```
$(function() {
    $('#navigation_list a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        toggleNav();
    });
});
```

Comment: I dont know if its the correct way to do it but ive just put this under my script and doesnt work. Sorry i dont know scripts at all (yet).